# How to organize a lightning node so that the liquidity is self balancing?

Tags: lightning-network, ln-channel-balance-management

Does anyone here know a method to organize a lightning node so that it becomes self balancing? By self balancing I mean that the liquidity is "mostly" balanced so that transactions flow in and then out without the need to perform rebalancing or use any other method of aquiring liquidity.

Thank you.